# How do you get GPM IMERG data in R?

Tags: r, gpm

I want to get proper GPM IMERG data with variables including time in R and work with it. I used  "https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/" and got the link list in txt file. I don't know what to do from here. Could someone give an idea?

Comment: First, download the data. IMERG is distributed with different time resolutions. Each file contains one timestep, so isn't a multidimensional time file. Use terra library to open the file in R

Comment: Could you help me walk through this? I have downloaded the nc4 files using wget, 265 in total. I'm unable to use terra maybe because I'm still quite new and unfamiliar with using new pacakges. my idea is  to combine these files into a single so I can compare with different sets of observations.

Answer (score 0):

Terra can open IMERG rasters, but these files don't have CRS and are flipped, so you must correct them before computing or implementing any analysis. In this case, I list the files inside a folder, then I iterate through files opening, correcting the X Y dimension (transposing the file), adding the CRS, and saving the result to a list):

```
library(terra)

fnames <- list.files(pattern = 'IMERG')

rlist <- list()

for (i in seq_along(fnames)) {
  r = rast(fnames[i])
  r = trans(r)
  ext(r) = c(-180,180,-90,90)
  crs(r) = "epsg:4326"
  rlist[[i]] = r
}
```

Then, you can perform any arithmetic operation or zonal stats or whatever you want to achieve.

If you need only one band, the process is faster:

```
rlist <- list()

for (i in seq_along(fnames)) {
  r = rast(fnames[i])['precipitationCal']
  r = trans(r)
  ext(r) = c(-180,180,-90,90)
  crs(r) = "epsg:4326"
  rlist[[i]] = r
}

plot(app(rast(rlist), sum), type = "interval",
     breaks = c(0.1,5,10,20,50,100))
```

[image]

I also post the same process with python using a custom function:

```
import rioxarray as rioxr

def load_imerg(file, var):
  da = rioxr.open_rasterio(file, engine='h5netcdf')
  da = da[0][var]
  return da.assign_coords({"x": (da.x / 10) - 90}) \
      .assign_coords({"y": (da.y / 10) - 180}) \
      .transpose('band', 'x', 'y') \
      .rio.write_crs(4326) \
      .rename({'x': 'y', 'y': 'x'})
```

You can loop using this function saving the results to a list as well.

I'm working with 30" product, so I found Python solution faster than R for doing the same task over thousands files.